# 2015 MacBook Pro 13" screen on a 2015 MacBook Air 13"

Tags: macbook-pro, display

Can I replace the display in my 2015 MacBook Air 13" for a 2015 MacBook Pro 13" one? Would it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may work, but at the least, you won't be able to close it properly. The LVDS cable is similar, but not identical, so you may have some extra cable parts floating around inside the enclosure. Short answer: it may work, but it is definitely not recommended. The way the top case (display) connects is slightly different. The screws would fit in the correct spots, but because the display is of different depths, it would not close properly.